# Subset of an inner product space

Tags: functional-analysis

Lets say you have and Inner product space $V$ and we are told that $A$ is a subset of $V$.

If I am asked if $A$ is a subspace of $V$, does one have to show that $A $is a subspace from the rules of showing closure of addition, multiplication and has zero vector. Or do we have to show that the inner product is the same on this space?

Thanks.
Thomas

Comment: What does it mean to show that "the inner product is the same on this space"?

Answer (score 2):

Whether $A$ is a vector subspace of $V$ depends only on the vector space structure of $V$ and how $A$ sits with respect to that structure. In any case, one can simply restrict the inner product $B : V \times V \to \Bbb R$ on $V$ to a map $B \vert_{A \times A}$. If $A$ is a vector subspace of $V$ and $B$ is positive-definite (sometimes positive-definiteness is taken as part of the definition of inner product) then checking the axioms quickly shows that $B \vert_{A \times A}$ is automatically an inner product on $A$.

On the other hand, given an inner product space $(V, B)$, a subspace $A$, and an inner product $C$ on $A$, we can ask whether the inner product structures are compatible---this just means that the inner product $C$ on $A$ is the same as the inner product $B\vert_{A \times A}$ it inherits from the ambient inner product space $(V, B)$.

Answer (score 1):

Formally, to prove it is a *subspace* you just have to show closure. However, if you want to show it is an *inner product subspace*, you have to make sure the inner product is defined correctly on the limited subset...

Comment: which is completely trivial if the inner product on $A$ is defined to be whatever it was on $V$.

Comment: @mathematician i am just not sure it will always function as intended on the limited set, but indeed cannot pick a counterexample

Comment: Closure alone will not do. Also $0$ vector must belong to the subspace.

Comment: @Hirak -- it will, since $0\cdot \vec{v} = \vec{0}$